# PHP File Upload Partial Upload Error

Tags: php, file-upload, nginx

I am stuck on a question concerning file uploads. I am trying to upload images that are either JPG, JPEG or PNG to a folder. I was reading a book and following their examples and my code is now like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Upload an Image</title>
    <style type="text/css" title="text/css" media="all">
        .error {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #C00;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php # Script 11.2 - upload_image.php

// Check if the form has been submitted:
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    // Check for an uploaded file:
    if (isset($_FILES['upload'])) {

        // Validate the type. Should be JPEG or PNG.
        $allowed = array ('image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/JPG', 'image/X-PNG', 'image/PNG', 'image/png', 'image/x-png');
        if (in_array($_FILES['upload']['type'], $allowed)) {

            // Move the file over.
            if (move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "upload/{$_FILES['upload']['name']}")) {
                echo '<p><em>The file has been uploaded!</em></p>';
            } // End of move... IF.

        } else { // Invalid type.
            echo '<p class="error">Please upload a JPEG or PNG image.</p>';
        }

    } // End of isset($_FILES['upload']) IF.

    // Check for an error:
    if ($_FILES['upload']['error'] > 0) {
        echo '<p class="error">The file could not be uploaded because: <strong>';

        // Print a message based upon the error.
        switch ($_FILES['upload']['error']) {
            case 1:
                print 'The file exceeds the upload_max_filesize setting in php.ini.';
                break;
            case 2:
                print 'The file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE setting in the HTML form.';
                break;
            case 3:
                print 'The file was only partially uploaded.';
                break;
            case 4:
                print 'No file was uploaded.';
                break;
            case 6:
                print 'No temporary folder was available.';
                break;
            case 7:
                print 'Unable to write to the disk.';
                break;
            case 8:
                print 'File upload stopped.';
                break;
            default:
                print 'A system error occurred.';
                break;
        } // End of switch.

        print '</strong></p>';

    } // End of error IF.

    // Delete the file if it still exists:
    if (file_exists ($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']) && is_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']) ) {
        unlink ($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
    }

} // End of the submitted conditional.
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_image.php" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="524288" />

    <fieldset><legend>Select a JPEG or PNG image of 512KB or smaller to be uploaded:</legend>

        <p><b>File:</b> <input type="file" name="upload" /></p>

    </fieldset>
    <div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It is strange as I have created the upload folder and set the relevant permissions on it and I can upload PNG files perfectly but when I try to upload JPG, **I keep getting an error of "file was only partially uploaded" as per the $errors array output.** The files in question are not large and are around 60-80 Kb. **I am new to this and was just wondering if there is anything glaringly wrong with the code above that would cause this error or if it is the server?**

I have also configured my php.ini and I have set file_uploads on. I am running PHP 5.6 with Nginx on Ubuntu.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If PNG uploaded OK, there should not be any problem with JPEG. It seems that server have problems with image size.

Comment: I agree, file size may be the problem here. Please check the upload with other JPG file, the one you use may be corrupted somehow. And try to add this MIME type to your list - "image/jp2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because `in_array` is **case sensitive**. Rather use `strtolower()` and make your mime-types lower case.

```
$allowed = array ('image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/x-png', 'image/png');
if (in_array(strtolower($_FILES['upload']['type']), $allowed)) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 if($_FILES['upload']['name'] != ''){
     $allowed_ext = array("gif","jpg","jpeg","png","GIF","JPG","JPEG","PNG"); 
     $filename = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
     $ext = end(explode(".", $filename));
     if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_ext)){echo '<p class="error">Please upload a JPEG or PNG image.</p>';}
     else{
          $rand1 = time();
          $image_name = $rand1.'.'.$ext;            //for rename image name
          $path = "upload/".$image_name;            //for image path
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $path);
     }
}
```

?>